# Unable to access apex class private variables in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm trying to write a unit test code for the below method but despite using @TestVisible annotation also I'm not able to access the local variables inside my test class. Is there anything I'm missing.

```
public void inactiveUsers(){

       // List<String> excludedUserList = getExcludedUsers();

        List<user> UserList = new List<user>();       

         List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

       @TestVisible DateTime dateBefore_90days = Date.today().addDays(Integer.valueof(Label.Secure_provisioning_90_days_notification.trim())*-1);

         @TestVisible string d = dateBefore_90days.format('yyyy-MM-dd');

        system.debug(Integer.valueof(Label.Secure_provisioning_90_days_notification.trim())*-1+'###'+d);

        string query = 'SELECT Id,email,username,lastlogindate FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE and DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(LastLoginDate)) <= '+ d;

        system.debug('###query##'+query);

        selectedUsers = Database.query(query);

        system.debug('Secure_provisioning_90days_notification list### '+selectedUsers);



        for(User record: selectedUsers) {

            record.IsActive = false;

            UserList.add(record);



            Messaging.Singleemailmessage email = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();

            //  email.setSenderDisplayName('Optum Inactive User Notification');

            email.setToAddresses(new String[]{record.email});

            email.setCCAddresses( new String[]{Label.Secure_provisioning_cc_email_address});

            email.setTargetObjectId(record.id);

            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);

            String body = getHTMLBody90days(record);

            email.setHtmlBody(body);

            email.setSubject('Your Access has been revoked');

            email.setUseSignature(false);

            emailsList.add(email);

        }
```

here is my test code.

```
static testMethod void myTest() {
        DeactivateInactiveUsers.dateBefore_90days = Date.today(); // getting error: Variable does not exist: dateBefore_90days
        DeactivateInactiveUsers.d = 'some value';  

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to access a local variable declared within a method. The correct way is to declare a class member variable and annotate it as test visible and you should be able to make it work.

Comment: Did n't work either.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared local variables in `inactiveUsers()` method which you are trying to access in your test class. This is not possible.

The correct way is to declare the variables at class level and annotate them with `@TestVisible`. Also, you need to instantiate an object of the class your are trying to test if the variable is not `static`.

Eg.

```
public class MyClass {
    @TestVisible
    private DateTime myDateTime;

    ...
}

// Test class
@IsTest(SeeAllData=false)
private class MyClassTests {

    @isTest
    static void shouldTest(){
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.myDateTime = DateTime.now();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to test a method is to call it and assert the expected public results which in your case is to send emails that have specific content. Tying your tests to internal detail in a method makes it hard to make any future changes to the design.

The sending email case is a bit hard to test but this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157145/unit-test-testing-emails/157170#157170) explains one technique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such variable "dateBefore_**60**days" in your actual class. It is "dateBefore_**90**days".

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected it.